# Push elements into immutable map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an immutable map, and I am iterating over an array, building objects that I want to push into that immutable map. What is the appropriate way to do so? Here is what I have:

```
let arrayOfNames = ['John', 'Lisa'];

arrayOfNames.forEach(function(name) {
  let id = generateId();
  let newPerson = {
    id: id,
    name: name,
  };

  // people is the immutable map
  people.set(id, newPerson);
});
```

console.log(people) // This doesn't have John or Lisa inserted, because well, people is immutable.

I know how I can insert one and assign it to a new variable:

`let newPeople = people.set('3', {id: 3, name: 'John'});`

But how would I do it when I have a loop to go through?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign `people` inside loop.

```
let people = ... // notice let not const

arrayOfNames.forEach(function(name) {
  let id = generateId();
  let newPerson = {
    id: id,
    name: name,
  };

  // people is the immutable map
  people = people.set(id, newPerson);
});
```

```js
let people = new Immutable.Map();

['Alice', 'Jane'].forEach((name, id) => {
  people = people.set(id, {id, name})
})

console.log(people)

// or using reduce

const people2 = ['John', 'Peter'].reduce((map, name, id) => map.set(id, {id, name}), new Immutable.Map)

console.log(people2)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immutable@3.8.1/dist/immutable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to first "prepare" the new people map and then merge it with the existing map.

Like:

```
const newPeopleMap = Immutable.Map(['John', 'Lisa'].map(function(personName) {
    let id = generateId();
    let newPerson = {
        id: id,
        name: name,
    };

    return [id, newPerson];
}));

const newMergedPeopleMap = people.merge(newPeopleMap);
```

This way, you're not giving up immutability, which is why you're probably using Immutable.js in the first place. ;)